# Why does Python not find my modules when invoking from the command line as opposed to from PyCharm?

Tags: python, module, pycharm, command, prompt

Invoking my script works fine from within PyCharm

Project structure is as follows:

```
project_name
└── src
    ├─ bin
    │  └─ file_to_run.py
    └─ some_module
       └─ __init__.py
```

I'm invoking the script from command line with

`C:\path\to\venv\python.exe C:\foo\project_name\src\bin\file_to_run.py`

and it gives me

`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'some_module'`

I've tried setting various values for %PYTHONPATH% including

- `cd project_name && set PYTHONPATH=.`
- `set PYTHONPATH=C:\foo\project_name\src`
- `set PYTHONPATH=C:\foo\project_name\src\bin`
- `set PYTHONPATH=C:\foo\project_name\src\some_module`
- `set PYTHONPATH="C:\foo\project_name\src\some_module; C:\foo\project_name\src\some_module"`

and basically all of the combinations thereof, with quotes, without quotes, separated by colons and semicolons.

I've set a sources root in PyCharm, and when I run it in the IDE it has a script path, environment variables and working directory defined as well as the options 'add content roots' and 'add sources roots' 'to PYTHONPATH' checked.

I can't think of any more relevant information as to why it can't find that module.

Windows version 10, using the command prompt.

Comment: What do the import statements look like in your file_to_run.py file?

Comment: if you want to import `some_module` then you have to use `C:\foo\project_name\src` without `some_module` at the end

Comment: you may have two Python installed (PyCharm may have own version installed) and they may use different settings

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I wasn't activating my virtualenv before running so the python version was different as suggested by @furas.